# ValueError not enough arguments - when trying to access DLL function with ctypes

Tags: ctypes

I got ValueErrors when try to access following API documentation with ctypes:

```
doSomeThing(int *param1, 
            int **param2, 
            int **param3, 
            char **param4)
**Parameters**
param1
[in] Pointer to an integer. 
param2
[in, out] Pointer to an integer pointer. Will contain a pointer to a list of indexes [0.. param1-1] which can be looped over. 
param3
[in, out] Pointer to an integer pointer. Will contain a pointer to a list of param3 which can be looped over. The param3 are members of the following enumeration:
        enum EXAMPLE_TYPE
        {
            x = 0,
            y = 1,
                z = 2
        };
param4
[in, out] Pointer to a char pointer. Will contain a pointer to a list of strings which can be looped over

**Return value**
Status code value from the enumeration
```

This is the code:

```
print exemple_DLL
param1 = ctypes.c_int()
param2 = (ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)*1)()
param3 = (ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)*1)()
param4 = (ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)*50)()

exemple_DLL.doSomeThing(ctypes.byref(param1), ctypes.byref(param2), ctypes.byref(param3), ctypes.byref(param4))
```

**Printout:**

*ValueError: Procedure called with not enough arguments (16 bytes missing) or wrong calling convention
Error in  in line 33: 'exemple_DLL.doSomeThing(ctypes.byref(param1), ctypes.byref(param2), ctypes.byref(param3), ctypes.byref(param4))'*

Anyone have an idea what can be wrong in my function call using ctypes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, this has to be done:

```
param1 = ctypes.c_int32()
param2 = ctypes.c_int32()
param3 = ctypes.c_int32()
param4 = ctypes.c_int32()

exemple_Dll.doSomeThing(ctypes.byref(param1), ctypes.byref(param2), ctypes.byref(param3), ctypes.byref(param4))
```